# Android xml layout while customising gridview item

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am trying to create a custom gridview item which looks something like how the movies are shown in this image:

[image]

in the sense, that how they have an image at the top and two or three text views below it.
I have used the following XML code for this but i am not getting the required layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:textColor="@color/palletblue"
        android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtTitle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#878787"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtTitle2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#878787"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="2dip"

        />


</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Where am i going wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: sorry, but your layout is messed up. first of all you dont need the framelyout and a relativelayout doesn't have an orientation. try starting from top. add the image, below that add the textviews and so on, if you don't need a complex layout (things like price and rating) you could use a linearlayout with an vertical orientation..

Comment: Hi i tried what you said with an imageview and a textview below it in linear layout, but i am facing some issues where the layout becomes too big and the textview is not visible. Could you give some sample code on how to do it using relative layout? Thanks

Comment: if the image is too big try to scale it: android:scaleType="centerCrop" i.e. or hardcoding the imageview size / height in dip

Comment: no the image is fine. there is a lot of unneccesary space around it which is the problem. And also the text is not getting displayed.could you provide some sample code so i can decide where i am going wrong?

Comment: any thoughts on that?

Comment: if you provide your current xml i can have a look at it, but i can't do it for you, sorry